# Unable to display image in Data List View

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010

I tried to display my images in database using data list in visual studio.

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td runat="server" style="width:300px">
             <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  Height="184px" Width="120px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image", "images\\{0}") %>' PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("productID", "ProductDetails.aspx?productID={0}") %>' /><br />
             <p><b><asp:Label ID="productIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' /></b></p>
           <p>Price &nbsp;  <asp:Label ID="priceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("price","{0:C}") %>' /></p>
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

I got a column name "image". However, there is not any images displayed on the browser. Can somebody please help me fix with it? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the ImageButton to reference the `~/Images/` folder like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  ImageUrl='~/Images/<%# Eval("image") %>' ... />
```

Comment: I set the image column to varchar(100). Is it supposed to be image or varchar?

Comment: Based on **your code**, the `image` column needs to be a text column holding the name of the image ("myImage.png" for example)

Comment: Yup I put a path to my images already. For example, products/iphone/iphone5.jpg . But my image still does not appear.

Comment: Did you do try viewing the page source and see if the outputed source is correct?

Comment: Okay i fix already. I typed wrongly for my image path. Thanks for helps.